# Elasticsearch - How to filter nested aggregation bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter buckets for nested aggregations.

Mapping:

```
{
  "dev.directory.3" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "profile" : {
        "properties" : {
          "events" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
            }
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index data:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "dev.directory.3",
      "_type" : "profile",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "title" : "Project manager",
        "events" : [ 
          {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Event A",
          }, 
          {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "Event B",
          },
          {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "Event C",
          },
          {
            "id" : 4,
            "name" : "Event D",
          } 
        ],
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using this query and aggregation definition

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "events",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "events.id": [1, 2]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "events.name12": {
            "filter": {},
            "aggs": {
                "inner": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "events"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "events.name": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "events.name"
                            }
                        },
                        "events.name_count": {
                            "cardinality": {
                                "field": "events.name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "_source": ["email", "company_name", "events"]
}
```

What I am getting is from aggregation result is:

```
"aggregations": {
    "events.name12": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "filtered": {
        "doc_count": 4,
        "events.name": {
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Event A",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "Event B",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "Event C",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "Event D",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "events.name_count": {
          "value": 4
        }
      }
    }
```

I struggling with filtering buckets list only to provided event ids, so the result should be like:

```
"aggregations": {
    "events.name12": {
      "doc_count": 2,
      "filtered": {
        "doc_count": 2,
        "events.name": {
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Event A",
              "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
              "key": "Event B",
              "doc_count": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "events.name_count": {
          "value": 2
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're almost there, you simply need to add the filter on `events.id` in your aggregation as well, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "events",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "events.id": [
                  1,
                  2
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "events.name12": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "events"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "filter": {
            "terms": {
              "events.id": [
                1,
                2
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "events.name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "events.name"
              }
            },
            "events.name_count": {
              "cardinality": {
                "field": "events.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "_source": [
    "email",
    "company_name",
    "events"
  ]
}
```

The reason is that your query will correctly select all documents for which there are nested events with the specified event IDs, however, your aggregation will then work on all nested events from all selected documents. So you need to filter out all nested events from those documents that don't have the right IDs in the aggregation as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I've tried this one but it gets me no aggregation result, no buckets. I was surprised as well for that. Maybe some true data:

Comment: Sorry my bad, the filter needs to be inside the nested aggregation, otherwise it won't work... I've fixed it. Please try again.

Comment: Life saver! You'll get my rep! Thanks you! Anyways, that was tricky part to move nested upper aggregation and filter downwards...

Comment: Yes, just remember that the nested aggregation just sets the context so that you can work on it, hence the filter needs to go inside it.

Comment: inside agg `filter`, should be `term` instead of `terms`

Comment: @RashidulIslam nope since there are two terms, you need `terms` and not `term`

Comment: @Val One doubt, why do you specify `events.id` in array `[]` in `filter aggregation` .

Comment: @Gibbs because the terms query requires it

Comment: @Val My bad. Thanks. In `term query` we can specify `events.id:2` since it `terms` it has to check for multiple. Hence it required `[]`Am I correct?

Comment: @Val How can I convert this query in bodyBuilder.js syntax? any idea?